# CodeIgniter app shows 404 when moved to production

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-status-code-404

I've finished developing an app using CodeIgniter in my local machine, and moved it to the production server (live site) yesterday.

My problem is that when I load the site, it immediately shows me a "page not found" error (404). I'm 100% sure this has nothing to do with the server itself, since a clean CodeIgniter installation works perfectly fine.

I've changed the settings in config.php and database.php to reflect the new environment so it's supposed to work. The log file isn't showing anything helpful (only that it can't find index_php after loading the URI library).

Any idea how I can troubleshoot this?

Your help is so much appreciated.

Comment: is it a codeigniter styled 404?if it is it's just a problem with your url...

Comment: Yes it belongs to CodeIgniter. What do you mean a problem with my URL though? the variable base_url has been properly set (tried it with and without index.php at the end)

Comment: can you describe your setup with more detail?name of classes, folders etc. and the url you are trying to use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just found the issue. My default controller's file name started with a capital letter. I changed it to small (e.g.: 'example.php' instead of 'Example.php') and it worked.

I've wasted so much time on such a silly error. :(

Answer (score 0):

Double-check your Apache configuration. For example, if you're using mod_rewrite to get rid of index.php from the URLs on your local machine, then make sure Apache is configured to do the same in production.

Comment: Thanks, but as I mentioned it's not a server-side issue. I haven't changed any of the default routing options. 'index.php' is still showing in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Permissions issue? If it can't see the file at all (404), then Apache might not have access.

Comment: Which file should I give premission to? and what permission?

Answer (score 0):

Check what `RewriteBase` points to in .htaccess in the root directory. Were you perhaps developing in a subdirectory on your local machine, ie `http://localhost/devsite`? If the live site is not in a subdirectory (ie `www.yoursite.ext/site` then `RewriteBase` needs to be `/`.