# codeigniter not work at live page not found error on server

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

my codeigniter work perfectly on local host but not work at live.my codeigniter is latest version.i also try older.it always show me page not found on redirect.

routes.php setting is

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

i also upload htaccess on server.i tried in linux and window both.

htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: how is your local and remote htaccess line `RewriteBase /`?

Comment: Yes, please post your `.htaccess`.

Comment: htaccess updated in my question.please check this

Comment: What is the URL you're using to access the site and what directory is the site installed in? .htaccess is not a requirement for Codeigniter, try removing it completely. Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3970634/398242

Comment: What are your config.php URL settings? And are you sure that on live you app is root domain folder, not in subdirectory ?

Comment: What is your server, sometimes certain servers (GoDaddy) need a different .htaccess to work?

Answer (score 3):

you can do:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; //you can also leave blank this CI tend to find this by himself
$config['index_page'] = '';

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO'; //if not working try one of these:
     'PATH_INFO'        Uses the PATH_INFO
    | 'QUERY_STRING'    Uses the QUERY_STRING
    | 'REQUEST_URI'     Uses the REQUEST_URI
    | 'ORIG_PATH_INFO'  Uses the ORIG_PATH_INFO
```

and try this `.htaccess` i use for many sites

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

if not working yet, use a `phpinfo();` and check if mod_rewrite is `enabled`