# CodeIgniter: 404 Page Not Found on Live Server

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have been developing a small web application with CodeIgniter.  After testing it out locally I went to put it on my web server to allow a couple other people test out some features. While navigating to the site I get: -

> 404 Page Not Found error page

When viewing it in my local machine everything loads up and runs perfectly.

This is what I uploaded to the `public_html` directory:

```
application directory
system directory
assets directory (my assets for the site)
index.php
```

All of those are in the `public_html` directory.  Like I said, it does give me CodeIgniters 404 error page, so I do know it is at least seeing CodeIgniter.  I also tried changing the `$config['base_url']`, in the `config.php`, to my URL. Same error when changing that or leaving it blank.
I checked my routes, and all those seem correct.  Everything also loads up just fine when navigating to it on my local machine.

I also am not using a `.htaccess` file at this time

Any suggestions on what I should try?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: you can find your answer from this link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315316/codeigniter-not-work-at-live-page-not-found-error-on-server
and 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17630669/codeigniter-working-fine-on-local-but-not-on-web-server-404-error

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You are using MVC with OOPS Concept. So there are some certain rules.

1) Your class name (ie: controller name) should be start with capital Letter.

e.g.: your controller name is 'icecream'. that should be '**I**cecream'

In localhost it might not be compulsory, but in server it will check all these rules, else it can't detect the right class name.

Comment: Just a note: the **class name** and the **file name** both need to be title case (start with a capital letter). So if the class name is 'Icecream', the file name needs to be 'Icecream.php', otherwise, CodeIgniter will throw a 404 error.

Comment: I don't think on server it checks all these rules. It could be due to the simple fact that the server runs Linux which is case sensitive for file names...

Comment: This is the case, also must verity the controller files on the server, Because sometimes even you ftp the file with title case it will not replace properly & better way is first delete the controllers on the server & upload the files with proper file name.

Comment: Happened with me. I was using MacOS for development which has a case-insensitive file system by default but the production server was on Linux. Scratched by head for almost a day.

Answer (score 18):

Changing the first letter to uppercase on the file's name and class name works.

**file:** `controllers/Login.php`

**class:** `class Login extends CI_Controller { ... }`

The file name, as the class name, should starts with capital letter. This rule applys to models too.

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html

Answer (score 17):

There are a number of things you can check here. I'll go over each one with you.

**1,**
When moving to a live server from localhost(htdocs) you need to make sure that the version of PHP you are using is supported.

To test this:
Create an '**index.php**' file and add the below line only.

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Just press '**Ctrl + F**' and search "version". You will find the php version. It may need to be 5.3+ to support features.

**2,**
Check your **`config/config.php`** and check your `$config['base_url']` and `$config['index_page']` *screen shot below*

[image]

I recommend putting site name in the base url example: '`www.site.com/`'
but remove the index.php for cleaning.

**3,**
**MOST LIKELY THE REASON SO START WITH THIS**

It most likely is the .htaccess file. Here is mine Made by Elliot Haughton.
Put this in your root directory and change line 9 'RewriteBase /' if necessary.

```bash
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    # !IMPORTANT! Set your RewriteBase here and don't forget trailing and leading
    # slashes.
    # If your page resides at
    # http://www.example.com/mypage/test1
    # then use
    # RewriteBase /mypage/test1/
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin 
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

If none of the above works, give me a shout back and we'll step through it.

Comment: Thanks for attempting to help.  I have tried all of those suggestions and I am still getting errors.  I have tried with the base_url empty, and also tried with it set to my URL.

Comment: Also, when I set the .htaccess file, I no longer get CodeIgniters error page, instead it turns into an internal server error.  I have tried everything I could think of for the rewrite base.  This site is being uploaded as a subdomain of another site I have if that helps.  I have also uploaded another CodeIgniter app as a sub domain that I created couple months ago and it uploaded perfectly and works great.  Though when I upload this one the exact same way I get the errors I had been describing....

Comment: I was having troubles to reach to the URL's like: domain/catalog/$1, and those was fixed with the htacces file

Comment: @twigman08 You are getting internal server error because the htaccess file is not ending properly. At the end change `<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>` to `</IfModule>`

Comment: Following are all the possibilities
1-- htaccess
2-- application/config/config.php  
3-- Apache2 Allow override for www (sudo a2enmod rewrite)
4-- Camel case

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem. Changing controlers first letter to uppercase helped.

Answer (score 12):

I have solved this problem, please just make few changes

1- all controller class name should start with capital letter. i mean first letter of class should be capital . eg  we have controler with class name Pages

so it should be Pages not pages

2-  save the controller class Pages as  **`Pages.php`**   not `pages.php`

so first letter must be capital

same for model, model class first letter should be capital and also save model class as  **`Pages_model.php`**  not `page_model.php`

hope this will solve ur problem

Comment: after renaming all class files including models and library files i.e only initial letters in Uppercase it starts working. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

I was stuck with this approx a day i just rename filename "Filename" with capital letter and rename the controller class  "Classname". and it solved the problem.

```
**class Myclass extends CI_Controller{}
save file: Myclass.php**
```

> application/config/config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

Answer (score 3):

I am doing it on local and production server this way:

---

Routes:

```
$route['default_controller']   = 'Home_controller';
```

---

Files' names:

- in **controllers** folder: *Home_controller.php*
- in **models** folder: *Home_model.php*
- in **views** folder: *Home.php*

---

Home_controller.php:

```
       class Home_controller extends CI_Controller {

           public function index(){

              //loading Home_model
              $this->load->model('Home_model');

              //get data from DB
              $data['db_data']  = $this->Home_model->getData();

              //pass $data to Home.html
              $this->load->view('Home', $data);
           }
       }
```

---

Home_model.php:

```
       class Home_model extends CI_Model {
       ...
       }
```

---

There should be no more problems with cases anymore :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to add following line in root folder index.php after php starts:

```
ob_start();
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the `root/application/core/` folder files whether if you have used any of `MY_Loader.php`, `MY_Parser.php` or `MY_Router.php` files.

If so, please try by removing above files from the folder and check whether that make any difference. In fact, just clean that folder by just keeping the default index.html file.

I have found these files caused the issue to route to the correct Controller's functions.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Add following line in root folder index.php just after <?php starts:

> ob_start();