# CodeIgniter 404 Page Not Found On Godaddy

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I am having website built in CodeIgniter Its working fine on localhost but when i uploaded it online It is giving 404 Page Not Found . I am using godaddy Hosting Linux Server .

I tried placing a text file on same path it works fine it was to check i am accessing correct path

I am also unable to access index.php . If I opne www.mydomain.com/index.php it gives 404 Page Not Found

home controller code here carrentalschandigarh.com/file.txt
**My .htaccess file code is as below**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**Code Of My config.php**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Base Site URL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| URL to your CodeIgniter root. Typically this will be your base URL,
| WITH a trailing slash:
|
|   http://example.com/
|
| If this is not set then CodeIgniter will try guess the protocol, domain
| and path to your installation. However, you should always configure this
| explicitly and never rely on auto-guessing, especially in production
| environments.
|
*/
$config['base_url'] = '';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Index File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Typically this will be your index.php file, unless you've renamed it to
| something else. If you are using mod_rewrite to remove the page set this
| variable so that it is blank.
|
*/
$config['index_page'] = '';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| URI PROTOCOL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This item determines which server global should be used to retrieve the
| URI string.  The default setting of 'REQUEST_URI' works for most servers.
| If your links do not seem to work, try one of the other delicious flavors:
|
| 'REQUEST_URI'    Uses $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
| 'QUERY_STRING'   Uses $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
| 'PATH_INFO'      Uses $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']
|
| WARNING: If you set this to 'PATH_INFO', URIs will always be URL-decoded!
*/
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| URL suffix
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option allows you to add a suffix to all URLs generated by CodeIgniter.
| For more information please see the user guide:
|
| http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
*/
$config['url_suffix'] = '';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Language
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This determines which set of language files should be used. Make sure
| there is an available translation if you intend to use something other
| than english.
|
*/
$config['language'] = 'english';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Character Set
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This determines which character set is used by default in various methods
| that require a character set to be provided.
|
| See http://php.net/htmlspecialchars for a list of supported charsets.
|
*/
$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Enable/Disable System Hooks
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If you would like to use the 'hooks' feature you must enable it by
| setting this variable to TRUE (boolean).  See the user guide for details.
|
*/
$config['enable_hooks'] = FALSE;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Class Extension Prefix
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This item allows you to set the filename/classname prefix when extending
| native libraries.  For more information please see the user guide:
|
| http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html
| http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html
|
*/
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Composer auto-loading
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Enabling this setting will tell CodeIgniter to look for a Composer
| package auto-loader script in application/vendor/autoload.php.
|
|   $config['composer_autoload'] = TRUE;
|
| Or if you have your vendor/ directory located somewhere else, you
| can opt to set a specific path as well:
|
|   $config['composer_autoload'] = '/path/to/vendor/autoload.php';
|
| For more information about Composer, please visit http://getcomposer.org/
|
| Note: This will NOT disable or override the CodeIgniter-specific
|   autoloading (application/config/autoload.php)
*/
$config['composer_autoload'] = FALSE;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Allowed URL Characters
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This lets you specify which characters are permitted within your URLs.
| When someone tries to submit a URL with disallowed characters they will
| get a warning message.
|
| As a security measure you are STRONGLY encouraged to restrict URLs to
| as few characters as possible.  By default only these are allowed: a-z 0-9~%.:_-
|
| Leave blank to allow all characters -- but only if you are insane.
|
| The configured value is actually a regular expression character group
| and it will be executed as: ! preg_match('/^[<permitted_uri_chars>]+$/i
|
| DO NOT CHANGE THIS UNLESS YOU FULLY UNDERSTAND THE REPERCUSSIONS!!
|
*/
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Enable Query Strings
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| By default CodeIgniter uses search-engine friendly segment based URLs:
| example.com/who/what/where/
|
| By default CodeIgniter enables access to the $_GET array.  If for some
| reason you would like to disable it, set 'allow_get_array' to FALSE.
|
| You can optionally enable standard query string based URLs:
| example.com?who=me&what=something&where=here
|
| Options are: TRUE or FALSE (boolean)
|
| The other items let you set the query string 'words' that will
| invoke your controllers and its functions:
| example.com/index.php?c=controller&m=function
|
| Please note that some of the helpers won't work as expected when
| this feature is enabled, since CodeIgniter is designed primarily to
| use segment based URLs.
|
*/
$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
$config['controller_trigger'] = 'c';
$config['function_trigger'] = 'm';
$config['directory_trigger'] = 'd';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Error Logging Threshold
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You can enable error logging by setting a threshold over zero. The
| threshold determines what gets logged. Threshold options are:
|
|   0 = Disables logging, Error logging TURNED OFF
|   1 = Error Messages (including PHP errors)
|   2 = Debug Messages
|   3 = Informational Messages
|   4 = All Messages
|
| You can also pass an array with threshold levels to show individual error types
|
|   array(2) = Debug Messages, without Error Messages
|
| For a live site you'll usually only enable Errors (1) to be logged otherwise
| your log files will fill up very fast.
|
*/
$config['log_threshold'] = 0;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Error Logging Directory Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Leave this BLANK unless you would like to set something other than the default
| application/logs/ directory. Use a full server path with trailing slash.
|
*/
$config['log_path'] = '';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Log File Extension
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The default filename extension for log files. The default 'php' allows for
| protecting the log files via basic scripting, when they are to be stored
| under a publicly accessible directory.
|
| Note: Leaving it blank will default to 'php'.
|
*/
$config['log_file_extension'] = '';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Log File Permissions
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The file system permissions to be applied on newly created log files.
|
| IMPORTANT: This MUST be an integer (no quotes) and you MUST use octal
|            integer notation (i.e. 0700, 0644, etc.)
*/
$config['log_file_permissions'] = 0644;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Date Format for Logs
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Each item that is logged has an associated date. You can use PHP date
| codes to set your own date formatting
|
*/
$config['log_date_format'] = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Error Views Directory Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Leave this BLANK unless you would like to set something other than the default
| application/views/errors/ directory.  Use a full server path with trailing slash.
|
*/
$config['error_views_path'] = '';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Cache Directory Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Leave this BLANK unless you would like to set something other than the default
| application/cache/ directory.  Use a full server path with trailing slash.
|
*/
$config['cache_path'] = '';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Cache Include Query String
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Whether to take the URL query string into consideration when generating
| output cache files. Valid options are:
|
|   FALSE      = Disabled
|   TRUE       = Enabled, take all query parameters into account.
|                Please be aware that this may result in numerous cache
|                files generated for the same page over and over again.
|   array('q') = Enabled, but only take into account the specified list
|                of query parameters.
|
*/
$config['cache_query_string'] = FALSE;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Encryption Key
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If you use the Encryption class, you must set an encryption key.
| See the user guide for more info.
|
| http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html
|
*/
$config['encryption_key'] = 'partyusalife-7890';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Variables
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| 'sess_driver'
|
|   The storage driver to use: files, database, redis, memcached
|
| 'sess_cookie_name'
|
|   The session cookie name, must contain only [0-9a-z_-] characters
|
| 'sess_expiration'
|
|   The number of SECONDS you want the session to last.
|   Setting to 0 (zero) means expire when the browser is closed.
|
| 'sess_save_path'
|
|   The location to save sessions to, driver dependent.
|
|   For the 'files' driver, it's a path to a writable directory.
|   WARNING: Only absolute paths are supported!
|
|   For the 'database' driver, it's a table name.
|   Please read up the manual for the format with other session drivers.
|
|   IMPORTANT: You are REQUIRED to set a valid save path!
|
| 'sess_match_ip'
|
|   Whether to match the user's IP address when reading the session data.
|
| 'sess_time_to_update'
|
|   How many seconds between CI regenerating the session ID.
|
| 'sess_regenerate_destroy'
|
|   Whether to destroy session data associated with the old session ID
|   when auto-regenerating the session ID. When set to FALSE, the data
|   will be later deleted by the garbage collector.
|
| Other session cookie settings are shared with the rest of the application,
| except for 'cookie_prefix' and 'cookie_httponly', which are ignored here.
|
*/
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Cookie Related Variables
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| 'cookie_prefix'   = Set a cookie name prefix if you need to avoid collisions
| 'cookie_domain'   = Set to .your-domain.com for site-wide cookies
| 'cookie_path'     = Typically will be a forward slash
| 'cookie_secure'   = Cookie will only be set if a secure HTTPS connection exists.
| 'cookie_httponly' = Cookie will only be accessible via HTTP(S) (no javascript)
|
    | Note: These settings (with the exception of 'cookie_prefix' and
    |       'cookie_httponly') will also affect sessions.
    |
    */
    $config['cookie_prefix']    = '';
    $config['cookie_domain']    = '';
    $config['cookie_path']      = '/';
    $config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
    $config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Standardize newlines
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Determines whether to standardize newline characters in input data,
    | meaning to replace \r\n, \r, \n occurrences with the PHP_EOL value.
    |
    | This is particularly useful for portability between UNIX-based OSes,
    | (usually \n) and Windows (\r\n).
    |
    */
    $config['standardize_newlines'] = FALSE;

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global XSS Filtering
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Determines whether the XSS filter is always active when GET, POST or
    | COOKIE data is encountered
    |
    | WARNING: This feature is DEPRECATED and currently available only
    |          for backwards compatibility purposes!
    |
    */
    $config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cross Site Request Forgery
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Enables a CSRF cookie token to be set. When set to TRUE, token will be
    | checked on a submitted form. If you are accepting user data, it is strongly
    | recommended CSRF protection be enabled.
        |
    | 'csrf_token_name' = The token name
    | 'csrf_cookie_name' = The cookie name
    | 'csrf_expire' = The number in seconds the token should expire.
    | 'csrf_regenerate' = Regenerate token on every submission
    | 'csrf_exclude_uris' = Array of URIs which ignore CSRF checks
    */
    $config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
    $config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_test_name';
    $config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
    $config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
    $config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;
    $config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array();

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Output Compression
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Enables Gzip output compression for faster page loads.  When enabled,
    | the output class will test whether your server supports Gzip.
    | Even if it does, however, not all browsers support compression
    | so enable only if you are reasonably sure your visitors can handle it.
    |
    | Only used if zlib.output_compression is turned off in your php.ini.
    | Please do not use it together with httpd-level output compression.
    |
    | VERY IMPORTANT:  If you are getting a blank page when compression is enabled             it
    | means you are prematurely outputting something to your browser. It could
    | even be a line of whitespace at the end of one of your scripts.  For
    | compression to work, nothing can be sent before the output buffer is called
    | by the output class.  Do not 'echo' any values with compression enabled.
    |
    */
    $config['compress_output'] = FALSE;

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Master Time Reference
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Options are 'local' or any PHP supported timezone. This preference tells
    | the system whether to use your server's local time as the master 'now'
    | reference, or convert it to the configured one timezone. See the 'date
    | helper' page of the user guide for information regarding date handling.
    |
    */
    $config['time_reference'] = 'local';

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Rewrite PHP Short Tags
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If your PHP installation does not have short tag support enabled CI
    | can rewrite the tags on-the-fly, enabling you to utilize that syntax
    | in your view files.  Options are TRUE or FALSE (boolean)
    |
    | Note: You need to have eval() enabled for this to work.
    |
    */
    $config['rewrite_short_tags'] = FALSE;

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Reverse Proxy IPs
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If your server is behind a reverse proxy, you must whitelist the proxy
    | IP addresses from which CodeIgniter should trust headers such as
    | HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR and HTTP_CLIENT_IP in order to properly identify
    | the visitor's IP address.
    |
    | You can use both an array or a comma-separated list of proxy addresses,
    | as well as specifying whole subnets. Here are a few examples:
    |
    | Comma-separated:  '10.0.1.200,192.168.5.0/24'
    | Array:        array('10.0.1.200', '192.168.5.0/24')
    */
    $config['proxy_ips'] = '';
```

It is not duplicate of this 
[CodeIgniter: 404 Page Not Found on Live Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28709185/codeigniter-404-page-not-found-on-live-server)
Because it is not even loading index.php in starting

Comment: what is you URL?? and controller name??

Comment: This is url 
http://www.carrentalschandigarh.com/

My Home Controller is 
http://www.carrentalschandigarh.com/Home/Index

Comment: add you .htaccess too

Comment: I already included my .htaccess file code above

Comment: use this. `RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]`

Comment: I replaced my .htaccess file with your contents but its same 404

Comment: are sure about conteroller name?? can you show you controller files??

Comment: Sorry , Yes sure I can show the controller files code

Comment: you can see home controller code here

http://www.carrentalschandigarh.com/file.txt

Comment: is this wrking in local??

Comment: yes its working in local but when i uploaded it on hosting it is doing weird I am using godaddy linux hosting

Comment: is you controller file name is simple?? or caps??

Comment: My controller name is Home you can see in txt file I have shared

Comment: ok i am going to try it

Comment: Now my php filename is Home.php and class name is home but error is same you can see

Comment: Now my index.php is working fine But no controller is viewing the design

Comment: Like home/index is not opening the page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter: 404 Page Not Found on Live Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28709185/codeigniter-404-page-not-found-on-live-server)

Comment: Its Not exactly Dulicate Because In Starting It was not even Loading Index.php and was saying index.php not found 

So by making some improvements in index.php first  i got index.php worked only after that We Came look into Naming Problem

It was not a unique problem After seeing some other question on stack regarding problem in .htaccess It got .htaccess worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your all file names caps and controller name as simple

Ex : `Home.php` and inside controller `home`

and inside your URL anchor tags set all to simple **`home`** instead of **`Home`**

Comment: Solution was so Simple . But It Let us hang with it for some long . I think our controller file name should be always Home.php ( 'H' Capital ) and under controller Class name should be home.php 

I completely forget to apply this

This also implies to all Controllers 
Thanks for the help