# 404 when accessing Codeigniter page

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm having the same problem as [CodeIgniter: 404 Page Not Found on Live Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28709185/codeigniter-404-page-not-found-on-live-server).  Within application/controllers, I have Welcome.php like so:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    /**
     * Index Page for this controller.
     *
     * Maps to the following URL
 *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome
 *  - or -
 *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
 *  - or -
 * Since this controller is set as the default controller in
 * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
 *
 * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
 * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
 * @see https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
 */
public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('welcome_message');
}
```

However, when I go to mysite.com, mysite.com/welcome, mysite.com/Welcome and mysite.com/Welcome.php, I get a 404 each time.

My routes.php:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

I have a file, Home.php:

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {

  public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('general_model');
  }

  public function index() {
    $this->load->view("home/home_view");
  }

  /*
   public function coming(){
   $this->load->view("home/coming_soon_view");
   }
  */
 }
```

My .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond $1 !^(phpMyAdmin|index\.php|robots\.txt)
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
```

I'm really struggling to see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What is you `config['index']` var set to?

Comment: From within config.php?

Comment: yes, `$config['index_page']`

Comment: is mod_rewrite enabled?

Comment: @qwertzman how would I find out please?

Comment: @Kisaragi $config['index_page'] = 'index.php';

Comment: Google "php test mod_rewrite"

Answer (score 1):

I have this experience on shared hosting then somehow find on internet but forgot who is giving this example, maybe you can try it.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  # !IMPORTANT! Set your RewriteBase here and don't forget trailing and leading
  #  slashes.
  # If your page resides at
  #  http://www.example.com/mypage/test1
  # then use
  # RewriteBase /mypage/test1/
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
  # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
  # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you set your base_url to

```
$protocol = ( isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' ) ? 'https://' : 'http://';
$config['base_url'] = $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), "", $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```

Then this is all you will need in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
# → Internally route to /index.php
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

You can expand on it later, just use minimal setup right now.

Comment: I've tried that, and it works whenever I have $route['default_controller'] = "welcome"; but not $route['default_controller'] = "home";

Comment: I have now set it up, but whenever I go to tripmatcher.herokuapp.com/login, it just displays a 404, despite there being a login.php within my controllers.

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is what worked for me.