# 404 page not found error on live server when click on a link using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am using
`<a href="<?php echo base_url('View/page'); ?>">LINK</a>`
Method to load files and

`<a href="<?php echo site_url('View/page'); ?>">LINK</a>`
method to load other pages when click on a link 404 page not found error occured on live server

My .htaccess file looks like

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|

(.*)\.swf|forums|images|css|downloads|jquery|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

My `config.php` settings for the site url are:

```
$config['url_suffix'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Anyone help please in this matter...

Comment: for more plz check w3ccodes.com

Comment: This is my website facing this issue

Comment: unable to understand whats the problem kindly help

Comment: click on any link and you will see the error

Comment: both are empty and .htaccess code has been shared above

Comment: And what is $config['base_url'] which is what base_url uses..

Comment: Is View a controller and page a method in that controller? Not sure how you are intending to use the same kind of link to load "different" pages when they are the same link.

Comment: `$base  = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];        
$base .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url'] = $base;`

Comment: See base_url for the above error

Comment: TimBrownlaw kindly help

Comment: please change your `base_url to w3ccodes.com` like `base_url=`http://www.w3ccodes.com/' and try again.

Comment: @UsmanKhan I cant help as I have no idea what you are doing. You need to explain what View/page is?

Comment: If you read this, it might help ( read all the answers ) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28709185/codeigniter-404-page-not-found-on-live-server

Comment: ok I'll try to follow the instructions but still i am not clear

Answer (score 0):

You have configure the file routes.php.

More info:

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html