# routing giving me 404 although its configured

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

my routes.php looks as follows

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

$route['default_controller'] = 'auth';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = TRUE;

$route['deposit/new'] = 'deposit/baru';
$route['pulsa/hof'] = 'page/hof_pulsa';
```

i have a class of `Api.php` that looks as follows

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Api extends MY_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        check_cookie(get_cookie('smm_login'));
        if ($this->session->userdata('login')) {
            if (user() == false) exit(redirect(base_url('auth/logout')));
        }
    }
    public function regenerate() {
        $this->user_model->update(array('api_key' => $this->lib->generate_api_key()), array('id' => user()));
        $this->session->set_flashdata('result', array('alert' => 'success', 'title' => 'Berhasil.', 'msg' => 'API Key berhasil dibuat ulang.'));
        redirect(base_url('api/documentation'));
    }
    public function documentation() {
        if (!$this->session->userdata('login')) exit(redirect(base_url()));
        $this->render('public/api/documentation', ['page_type' => 'Dokumentasi API']);
    }
```

however when i navigate to mysite.com/api/documentation , it gives me a 404 .. why is it ?

**EDIT:**

i got the following error on my error log

```
AH00687: Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /var/www/site/api (None could be negotiated)., referer: http://www. site .com/
```

**EDIT 2**

I changed the class name from Api to Apii and it works.. FML , why can't i use Api ?

Comment: Q: Are *ANY* of your routes working?  Q: is it "api/documentation", or "public/api/documentation"... or does it matter?  SUGGESTIONS: 1) review the entries here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30207645/421195, 2) check your CI log files, 3) check your web server error log files

Comment: all my other routes are working

Comment: dump and die at the top of API to see if reaches it at all or not

Comment: i did a var_dump on the documentation method and it did not even go there

Comment: @SherifSalah added more error from apache2

Comment: @aherlambang its important to die after dump, and show me the error

Comment: @SherifSalah did you re-read my edit above ? I changed the class name to Api to Apii and it worked.. pulling my hair why it does that .. is Api a key word that can't be used in CI or what

Comment: @aherlambang i can't futher help without seeing the folder structure (controllers and core) and see if there are any special rules in .htaccess that rewrites api .. and no its not a keyword

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240088/discussion-between-sherif-salah-and-aherlambang).